Pimcore Copilot Select type Environment Variable Configuration
I am currently working on integrating Pimcore Copilot's variant generator into my project and have encountered a question regarding configuration flexibility. Specifically, I'd like to leverage the functionality of Options Providers and Options Provider Data within the "Environment Variable" configuration for a Select Type Field.
While I understand how to make the field mandatory or non-mandatory and provide static options, I am seeking guidance on how to dynamically populate the options using Options Providers. Is this currently supported within the Pimcore Copilot configuration framework?
If so, I would greatly appreciate it if someone could provide a sample configuration demonstrating how to achieve this. Any insights or code examples would be invaluable in streamlining my implementation.
Thank you in advance for your expertise and assistance.
